# GDTCCTUploadOperation.m:36:9: 'GoogleUtilities/GULURLSessionDataResponse.h' file not found

Tags: swift, firebase, cocoapods

I have updated my cocoapods
sudo gem install CocoaPods
and update my pods now I can't compile my iOS project

'GoogleDataTransport/GDTCCTLibrary/Private/GDTCCTUploadOperation.h' file not found

Also was getting  GULLogger.h  not found (before doing pod reintegrate)

Anyone have a solution or a reason why this is happening?

Thanks in advance

Podfile

```
pod 'SwiftyJSON'
pod 'GoogleMaps'
pod 'RealmSwift',  '=10.20.0'
pod 'AWSS3'
pod 'AWSCognito'
pod 'AWSMobileClient'
pod 'AWSPinpoint'
pod 'Plaid'
pod 'Firebase/Core'
pod 'FirebaseAnalytics'
pod 'FirebaseMessaging'
pod 'FirebaseAuth'
pod 'FirebaseFirestore'
pod 'FirebaseFunctions'
pod 'FirebaseInAppMessaging'
pod 'FirebaseInstanceID'
pod 'FirebasePerformance'
pod 'FirebaseRemoteConfig'
pod 'FirebaseCrashlytics'
pod 'Firebase/AdMob'
pod 'SwiftLint'
pod 'SwiftGen'
pod 'SDWebImage'
pod 'Reusable'
pod 'SYBadgeButton'
pod 'Instructions'


Downloading dependencies
Installing AWSAuthCore (2.19.1)
Installing AWSCognito (2.19.1)
Installing AWSCognitoIdentityProvider (2.19.1)
Installing AWSCognitoIdentityProviderASF (2.19.1)
Installing AWSCore (2.19.1)
Installing AWSMobileClient (2.19.1)
Installing AWSPinpoint (2.19.1)
Installing AWSS3 (2.19.1)
Installing BoringSSL-GRPC (0.0.7)
Installing Firebase (3.6.0)
Installing FirebaseABTesting (8.10.0)
Installing FirebaseAnalytics (3.4.2)
Installing FirebaseAnalyticsInterop (1.5.0)
Installing FirebaseAuth (8.10.0)
Installing FirebaseCore (8.10.0)
Installing FirebaseCoreDiagnostics (8.10.0)
Installing FirebaseCrashlytics (8.10.0)
Installing FirebaseFirestore (8.10.0)
Installing FirebaseFunctions (8.10.0)
Installing FirebaseInAppMessaging (0.13.0)
Installing FirebaseInstallations (8.10.0)
Installing FirebaseInstanceID (1.0.9)
Installing FirebaseMessaging (8.10.0)
Installing FirebasePerformance (8.10.0)
Installing FirebaseRemoteConfig (8.10.0)
Installing GTMSessionFetcher (1.7.0)
Installing Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK (7.11.0)
Installing GoogleDataTransport (9.1.2)
Installing GoogleInterchangeUtilities (1.2.2)
Installing GoogleMaps (6.0.1)
Installing GoogleSymbolUtilities (1.1.2)
Installing GoogleUtilities (1.3.2)
Installing GoogleUtilities (7.6.0)
Installing Instructions (2.1.1)
Installing Plaid (2.3.1)
Installing PromisesObjC (2.0.0)
Installing Realm (10.20.0)
Installing RealmSwift (10.20.0)
Installing Reusable (4.1.2)
Installing SDWebImage (5.12.1)
Installing SYBadgeButton (1.1.0)
Installing SwiftGen (6.5.1)
Installing SwiftLint (0.45.1)
Installing SwiftyJSON (5.0.1)
Installing abseil (0.20200225.0)
Installing gRPC-C++ (1.28.2)
Installing gRPC-Core (1.28.2)
Installing leveldb-library (1.22.1)
Installing nanopb (2.30908.0)
Generating Pods project
Integrating client project
```

Answer (score 2):

Try `pod deintegrate` and `pod update` and make sure that FirebaseAnalytics updates to match the other Firebase products. Also, the two versions of GoogleUtilities is problematic.

If `pod deintegrate` doesn't solve that issue, you'll likely need to dig deeper to understand what's causing the bad configuration. The Podfile.lock file should provide some clues.

Comment: Thanks Paul  Had done the deintegrate  before that didn't work.  I did notice that Firebase/AdMobs requires a different version of GoogleUtilities than the other Firebase modules  I'm wondering if that is an issue?

Comment: `Firebase/AdMob` has been deprecated in favor of `Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK`